# How to create several Jedis instances using JedisPool in a multithreaded environment

Tags: java, multithreading, connection-pooling, jedis

I tried to use JedisPool to create several Jedis instances for multithreading usage (each thread can have one Jedis instance). But when I tried to create multiple instances by using JedisPool.getResource(), it always gives me the same Jedis instance. And the following code will also give me `redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Unexpected end of stream` because of single Jedis instance for multiple threads.

```
private final static JedisPoolConfig poolConfig = buildPoolConfig();
private static JedisPool jedisPool = new JedisPool(poolConfig, "localhost");

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    MyThread[] myThreads = new MyThread[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < myThreads.length; i++) {
       try (Jedis jedis = jedisPool.getResource()) {
           System.out.println("jedis " + i  + ": "+ jedis);
           myThreads[i] = new MyThread(jedis);
           myThreads[i].start();
       }
    }
    jedisPool.close();
}

private static JedisPoolConfig buildPoolConfig() {
    final JedisPoolConfig poolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
    poolConfig.setMaxTotal(128);
    poolConfig.setMaxIdle(128);
    poolConfig.setMinIdle(16);
    poolConfig.setTestOnBorrow(true);
    poolConfig.setTestOnReturn(true);
    poolConfig.setTestWhileIdle(true);
    poolConfig.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(Duration.ofSeconds(60).toMillis());
    poolConfig.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(Duration.ofSeconds(30).toMillis());
    poolConfig.setNumTestsPerEvictionRun(3);
    poolConfig.setBlockWhenExhausted(true);
    return poolConfig;
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you give a glimpse on how you're using `Jedis` inside MyThread class?

Comment: @sazzad Inside MyThread, it will use jedis.exists() to see whether the specified key exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to use `JedisPool` in a multi-threaded environment. But, by your implementation, you are actually using `Jedis` in that situation.

To resolve that you can take `JedisPool` instead of `Jedis` for `MyThread` constructor.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    MyThread[] myThreads = new MyThread[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < myThreads.length; i++) {
        myThreads[i] = new MyThread(jedisPool);
        myThreads[i].start();
    }
    jedisPool.close();
}
```

During every operation in `MyThread` class, take a `Jedis` object from pool and use it. For example:

```
class MyThread {
    void doSomething() {
        try (Jedis jedis = jedisPool.getResource()) {
            jedis.exists(key);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying the same approach as mentioned in the question and getting different Jedis instance. What is incorrect with that approach. Each thread has own instance of Jedis, shouldn't that be thread safe